# Group by month in Hibernate Criteria queries

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

I am new to Hibernate Criteria Queries , I am struggling to get the count based on month.

```
   session.createCriteria(Task.class)                                                                           
  .add(Restrictions.eq("completed", true))                     
  .add(Restrictions.in("site", sites))  
  .setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
  //group by "completedTime"
```

If I have to get the count group By Month based on completedTime.
How can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Task.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("completed", true));                     
    criteria.add(Restrictions.in("site", sites));

    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.rowCount());
    projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("month"));

    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("completedTime"));
```

You need to create projectionList to add projected column in it.

**EDIT 1**

```
projectionList.add(Projections.property("month"));
```

add month also in projectionList , so that you can able to retrieve the value.

Comment: Thanks a million , I have one more doubt . Is there any way can get the month name for each count

Comment: groupProperty return the property also in result. no need to externally mention that.

Comment: Can you please verify now.